# Match all the text but html tag content

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna match the text outside the html tag div in the below example 
What is the Regex pattern that I should use? Thanks!

```html
Match me 1 <div>Hello World!</div> Match me 2.
```

Update: This is a free text not a well formatted HTML but it has custom/HTML tags inside it, I need to extract the text that is not inside a tag for further processing...

Comment: You shouldn't use regex at all. BTW: That is not well formed html. If that isn't a nested `<div>`, the second one should be a `</div>`.

Comment: 'Match me 1' and 'Match me 2' will also be inside a tag - the parent tag.

Comment: Yes, It is not a well formatted HTML, I have a free text and I wanted to process all the texts that is not inside tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use this pattern:

```
(^([\s\S]*?)(?=<div>))|(((?<=<\/div>))([\s\S]*?)(?=<div>))|((?<=<\/div>)[\s\S]*)
```

**How it works**

`^` Matches the beginning of the string

`\s` Matches any **whitespace** character (spaces, tabs, line breaks)

`\S` Matches any character that is **not a whitespace** character (spaces, tabs, line breaks)

`*` Match anything, `?` non-greedily (match the minimum number of characters required)

`|` Using to combine between one or more pattern

`()` Expression will match as a group

`(?=<div>)` It is a group construct, that requires the escaped `<div>`, before any match can be made.

**Why need `?` here?**

```
Match me1 <div><div>Hello World!</div> Match me 2 <div>Hello World!</div> Match me 3.
```

by default, regexes are greedy, meaning it will match as much as possible. Therefore if you use the above pattern it will select all the text till third `<div>` but by adding the non-greedy quantifier `?` makes the regex only select all the text till the first `<div>`